# How to curl -k -H with python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have this curl command:

```
curl -k -H "X-ApiTokenId: 11111111-2222-...." https://staging.mycompany.com/v1/users.json
```

and it works OK. But when I translate it into requests:

```
r=requests.get("https://staging.mycompany.com/v1/user.json",headers={'Authourization':'TOK:11111111-2222-....'})
```

it says "unauthorized to access this resource." How do I correct this?

Comment: Curl is using header `X-ApiTokenId` which is different from normal auth headers... As headers starting with `X-` are custom headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `X-ApiTokenId` to the `headers` (same as curl -H) and `verify=False` to ignore verifying the ssl cert (same is curl -k):

```
r=requests.get("https://staging.mycompany.com/v1/user.json",headers={'X-ApiTokenId':'11111111-2222-....'}, verify=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really appreciate it. However, I am still getting the same issue unauthorized to access this resource. This is after I change the header  by adding 'X-ApiTokenId':'TOK: 1111111-2222.....' Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @PeterChao Can you try the updated code as well as pasting the entire error you are receiving?

Comment: I get : The result is: 401

Comment: r.text will return the following:

Comment: {"errors":[{"type":"error","href":null,"id":"e57853d7-8043-4505-a6f8-7b9345688c6b","status":401,"code":"unauthorized","title":"Unauthorized","detail":"You are unauthorized to access this resource","links":{},"path":null}]}

Comment: can you paste what the headers looks like you tried?

Comment: r = requests.get ('https://staging.comanyxyz.com/v1/users.json',headers={'X-ApiTokenId':'TOK:cc4iidje-282s-3kkk-bfea-111111111111'})

Comment: Delete the TOK: part of your header.

Comment: I got it. I found out what is wrong, and now it works.